# Validating inputs using function

Tags: c++

I really needed help here on how to write an input validation using function. I know while loop validation, but in this case I really wanted to know how to write a function to validate my inputs so that I can call the function from my inputs to take care of incorrect inputs.

In my code, I accept integers from user inputs and characters:

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;


//Function Declarations

//Shouf shouf Habibi row.



int shouf_normal (int a, int b )
{

    int shouf_normal=a* b;


    return shouf_normal; 


}

int shouf_Premium(int b, int c)
{

  int shouf_premium=b*c;

  return shouf_premium;



}


//The interview row

double interview_normal(double c, double d)

{

    double interview_normal=(c*d);

    return interview_normal;
}


double interview_premium(double d, double e)

{

    double interview_premium=d*e;

    return interview_premium;
}

//New Kids turbo row

int turbo_normal(int e, int f)
{

    int turbo_normal=e*f;

    return turbo_normal;

}


// The Butterflies row


int butterflies_normal(int f, int g)
{

    int butterflies_normal=f*g;

    return butterflies_normal;

}

int main()
{


    cout<<"\n\t"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|******************************************************************|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|Welcome to A31 Cinema, where you watch latest and cheapest movies.|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|******************************************************************|"<<endl;

    cout<<"\n\tBelow are the movies screening lists.\n\tThe price of tickets are given according to seats classes\n\tand quality of movie."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\tNote:Glassses for 3D movies cost $3.00."<<endl;
    cout<< "\t__________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t| Movie Title         |      Normal         |      Premium         |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|______________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|1.Shouf Shouf Habibi |        $5.00        |      $7.00           |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|______________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|2.The Interview (3D) |        $7.00        |     $9.50            |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|______________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|3.New Kids Turbo (3D)|        $7.00        |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|4.Black Butterflies  |        $5.00        |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|"<<endl;


    //constant initials

    const int a=5;
    const int b=7;
    const double c=7;
    const double d=9.5;
    const int e=7;
    const int glass=3;
    const int f=5;
    double total_tickets=0;
    int choice=0; 
    int number=0;
    char reply;

    bool correct_entry=true;
    string not_int;
    int not_char;


    cout<<"\n\tPlease choose from the lists (1-4) above and press enter:";

    cin>>number;
    while(number>=1 && number<=4)
    {

        if (number==1)
        {

            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"Shouf Shouf Habibi\".";
            cout<<"\n\tFor Normal; Press \"N\" or for premium class; Press \"P\":";
            cin>>reply;

           if(reply=='N'|| reply=='n')
           {
            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Normal class."<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
            cin>>choice;

            total_tickets=shouf_normal(a,choice);
            cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;  //calculating & printing out cost 
           }
          if(reply=='P'||reply=='p') 
          {

            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Premium class."<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
            cin>>choice;

            total_tickets=shouf_Premium (b,choice);
            cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;  //calculating & printing out cost 
          }



        }

       if(number==2)
       {
        cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"The interview\"in 3D quality.";
        cout<<"\n\tFor Normal; press \"N\" or for premium class; Press \"P\":";
        cin>>reply;


         if(reply=='N'|| reply=='n')
         {
          cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Normal class.";
          cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
          cin>>choice;
          total_tickets=interview_normal(c,choice)+(glass*choice);

          cout<<"\n\t Price for one ticket is $"<<c<<endl;
          cout<<"\n\tPrice for one 3D glass is $"<<glass<<endl;
          cout<<"\n\t Your total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;


         }

         if(reply=='P'|| reply=='p')
            {
             cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Premium class.";
             cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
             cin>>choice;
             total_tickets=interview_premium(d,choice)+(glass*choice);

             cout<<"\n\t Price for one ticket is $"<<d<<endl;
             cout<<"\n\tPrice for one 3D glass is $"<<glass<<endl;
             cout<<"\n\t Your total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;





            }


       }

     if(number==3)
     {

        cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"The New Kids Turbo\" in 3D quality.";
        cout<<"\n\tThis moview is available only in Normal class.";
        cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
        cin>>choice;
        total_tickets=turbo_normal(e,choice)+(glass*choice);

             cout<<"\n\t Price for one ticket is $"<<e<<endl;
             cout<<"\n\tPrice for one 3D glass is $"<<glass<<endl;
             cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;




     }
     if (number==4)
     {
       cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"Black Butterflies\".";
       cout<<"\n\tThis Movie is available only in Normal class.";
       cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
       cin>>choice;   
       total_tickets=butterflies_normal(f,choice);
       cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;  


     }
        cout<<"\n\tPlease choose from the lists (1-4) above and press enter or \n\t press \"Q\" to quit:";
        cin>>number; 

        while( number!=(number>=1&& number<=4))
        {
        cout<<"\n\tPlease choose from the lists (1-4) above and press enter or \n\t press \"Q\" to quit:";
        cin>>number; 

        }

        if(number=='Q'|| number=='q')
        {
            cout<<"\n\t\tThank You purchasing movie tickets with us!"<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). SO is not a service where you could just dump your entire code and have someone fix it for you. If you have a specific question about a problem with a [mcve], please ask.

Comment: i think putting my entire code will help us all understand what the code is about.

Comment: You think wrong. The help center is full of information about what [you can ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), what [you can't ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The last link is especially pertinent to your question, because it's of low quality.

Comment: oh im sorry about that

Comment: I was actually going to give you some useful advice on that other question, but you deleted it while I was still writing it up. Bad luck. :-/

Comment: okay re-post now

Answer (score 0):

`cin` has `fail()` method that can be use to check if a read was successful or not, with conjuncture of properly placed code.

Try this:

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;
//Function Declarations
//Shouf shouf Habibi row.

int shouf_normal (int a, int b )
{   
    int shouf_normal=a* b;
    return shouf_normal; 
}

int shouf_Premium(int b, int c)
{
  int shouf_premium=b*c;
  return shouf_premium;
}

//The interview row
double interview_normal(double c, double d)
{
    double interview_normal=(c*d);
    return interview_normal;
}

double interview_premium(double d, double e)
{
    double interview_premium=d*e;
    return interview_premium;
}

//New Kids turbo row
int turbo_normal(int e, int f)
{
    int turbo_normal=e*f;
    return turbo_normal;
}

// The Butterflies row
int butterflies_normal(int f, int g)
{
    int butterflies_normal=f*g;
    return butterflies_normal;
}

void display_menu() {
    cout<<"\n\t"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|******************************************************************|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|Welcome to A31 Cinema, where you watch latest and cheapest movies.|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|******************************************************************|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\tBelow are the movies screening lists.\n\tThe price of tickets are given according to seats classes\n\tand quality of movie."<<endl;
    cout<<"\n\tNote:Glassses for 3D movies cost $3.00."<<endl;
    cout<<"\t___________________________________________________________________"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t| Movie Title         |       Normal        |      Premium         |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|______________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|1.Shouf Shouf Habibi |        $5.00        |      $7.00           |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|______________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|2.The Interview (3D) |        $7.00        |      $9.50           |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|______________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|3.New Kids Turbo (3D)|        $7.00        |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|4.Black Butterflies  |        $5.00        |"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t|_____________________|_____________________|"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    //constant initials
    const int a=5;
    const int b=7;
    const double c=7;
    const double d=9.5;
    const int e=7;
    const int glass=3;
    const int f=5;
    double total_tickets=0;
    int choice=0; 
    int number=0;
    char reply;

    bool correct_entry=true;
    string not_int;
    int not_char;


    while(true){

        display_menu();

        do {
            cout<<"\n\tPlease choose from the lists (1-4) above and press enter or \n\tPress any other key to quit:";
            cin>>number;

            // You cannot check number for Q or q because number is int, and Q/q is char
            if(cin.fail()) {
                cout<<"\n\t\tThank You purchasing movie tickets with us!"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }

        } while(number < 1 && number > 4 );

        if (number==1) {
            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"Shouf Shouf Habibi\".";
            cout<<"\n\tFor Normal; Press \"N\" or for premium class; Press \"P\":";
            cin>>reply;

           if (reply=='N'|| reply=='n') {
            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Normal class."<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
            cin>>choice;

            total_tickets=shouf_normal(a,choice);
            cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;  //calculating & printing out cost 

           } else if(reply=='P'||reply=='p'){

            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Premium class."<<endl;
            cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
            cin>>choice;

            total_tickets=shouf_Premium (b,choice);
            cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;  //calculating & printing out cost 
          }
        } else if(number==2) {
            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"The interview\"in 3D quality.";
            cout<<"\n\tFor Normal; press \"N\" or for premium class; Press \"P\":";
            cin>>reply;

            if(reply=='N'|| reply=='n'){
                cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Normal class.";
                cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
                cin>>choice;
                total_tickets=interview_normal(c,choice)+(glass*choice);

                cout<<"\n\t Price for one ticket is $"<<c<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\tPrice for one 3D glass is $"<<glass<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\t Your total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;
            } else if  (reply=='P'|| reply=='p') {
                cout<<"\n\tYou have selected Premium class.";
                cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
                cin>>choice;
                total_tickets=interview_premium(d,choice)+(glass*choice);

                cout<<"\n\t Price for one ticket is $"<<d<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\tPrice for one 3D glass is $"<<glass<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\t Your total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;
            }
        } else if(number==3) {

                cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"The New Kids Turbo\" in 3D quality.";
                cout<<"\n\tThis moview is available only in Normal class.";
                cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
                cin>>choice;
                total_tickets=turbo_normal(e,choice)+(glass*choice);

                cout<<"\n\t Price for one ticket is $"<<e<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\tPrice for one 3D glass is $"<<glass<<endl;
                cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl;
        } else if(number==4) {

            cout<<"\n\tYou have selected \"Black Butterflies\".";
            cout<<"\n\tThis Movie is available only in Normal class.";
            cout<<"\n\tPlease choose the number of tickets you want:";
            cin>>choice;   
            total_tickets=butterflies_normal(f,choice);
            cout<<"\n\tYour total costs is=$"<<total_tickets<<endl; 
        } 

        // Wait for user to enter some key so that they can view their bill.
        cout<<endl<<"Press any key to continue....";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```